# Regex to check for existance of 1 or more characters - javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How to test the following pattern using `regex` - Javascript

`String`:   localhost:5000/submissionForm/1540186380266/true?cf=true 
`Pattern`: `any string`/submissionForm/`any string`/true?cf=true

Based on the suggested answer, tried with following code, but it returns false

```
var str = "localhost:5000/submissionForm/1540186380266/true?cf=true";
var patt = new RegExp('^[^\/]+\/submissionForm\/[^\/]+\/true\?cf=true$');
var res = patt.test(str);
console.log(res); // false
```

Comment: ```/.*?\/submissionForm\/.*?\/true\?cf\=true/```

Comment: @hanshenrik, `=` does not need to be escaped:  https://regex101.com/r/teQsz6/1

Comment: Double escape the backslash before the questionmark for the RegExp constructor `var patt = new RegExp('^[^/]+\/submissionForm\/[^/]+\/true\\?cf=true$');`

Comment: @Prem see https://i.imgur.com/R6lvVAe.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try regex, `^[^/]+\/submissionForm\/[^/]+\/true\?cf=true$`

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/7BvMSk/3)

Comment: You don't need to escape `/` inside brackets.